# Query to list all tables in a schema

Tags: db2

I am using Rational Application Developer to run querys on a database. We are unable to locate anyone who has a list of the tables on the schema and so far the queries we have found to get a list of tables are unsuccessful.

```
USE <DB>
GO
SELECT *
FROM sys.Tables
GO
```

Use breaks but I replaced it with CALL.

GO breaks as well and I cannot locate a function that does the same thing.

Comment: How does `GO` break?  Sounds painful.  Probably you should mention what errors do you get?

Comment: Since there is divergent answers based upon the system you are running DB2 on can you answer that question? Are you running DB2 on Linux? Unix? Windows? i5/OS (aka AS/400)? z/OS?

Answer (score 2):

The given statement smells like MS SQL-Server, not like DB2.

According to [IBM Documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008443.html) I think SYSCAT.TABLES is the view you are looking for.

Comment: Yes. Specifically you want select tabname from syscat.tables where tabschema = 'my_schema';

Comment: Again, this is not DB2 specific, and does not contain *nearly* as much information as SYSTABLES, or SQLTABLES.

Comment: @WarrenT -- What is not DB2-specific, if I may ask? DB2 documentation?

Comment: @WarrenT - either option will work fine (SYSTABLES or TABLES). One is the system catalog table, the other is a system catalog view. Given what Aaron has requested above, the view will be just as fine as the table.

Answer (score 2):

While @user22610's answer will work great if your DB2 platform is Linux/Unix/Windows, it will not work on Mainframe DB2 (z/OS). If you're using that platform, this would be your command:

```
SELECT *
FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES
WHERE CREATOR = @schema
```

Comment: by mainframe DB2, do you mean DB2 for i, or DB2 for z?

Comment: I meant z/OS, and edited the question. For some reason, I don't really think of iSeries as "Mainframe". I guess I'm a little biased. :)

Comment: well...I guess technically you are correct. iSeries is probably what would be called a midrange server I think.

Answer (score 1):

You were close...  leave the period out of "SYSTABLES"

```
SELECT *
  FROM SYSTABLES;
```

SYSTABLES is the DB2 standard catalog view. Where you find it depends on which flavor of DB2 server you are using: DB2 for i, LUW, or z/OS.

You shouldn't need GO or other such fiddle-faddle.

Right click on a statement in the SQL file editor, and you'll see options like alt-S to execute current text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select table_name from information_schema.tables
```

Comment: Aaron is looking for the specific query to execute (ie, specific to DB2). Not to be too blunt, but this generic statement is not helpful.

Comment: well, not to be blunt myself, but msi77 answer was the only one working for me, in a DB2. I tried all others around the web (more than 20 different) with all kind of errors.